# Parse Full USA Street Address into Address, City, State, Zip

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have addresses that follow this format every time:

Address, City, State Zip

Example: 555 Test Drive, Testville, CA 98773

I would like to parse the address into separate variables for:

- Address
- City
- State
- Zip

I have tried some preg_match examples but they don't follow the same pattern I am using. Is it regex or preg_match im looking for? Please help!

Comment: The pattern I see here is `text, text, text text`. Which can be captured using `(.*),(.*), (.*) (.*)`. And four groups can be captured in different variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are absolutely positive the addresses will always be formatted just like your example, with those commas, you have two simple options.

#### Option 1: Regex

```
preg_match("/(.+), (\w+), (\w+) (\w+)/", $address, $matches);
list($original, $street, $city, $state, $zip) = $matches;
```

Now you have your individual address variables.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/veo0i

#### Option 2: Explode

You can also use `explode()` to pull apart the address into pieces:

```
list($street, $city, $statezip) = explode(", ", $address);
list($state, $zip) = explode(" ", $statezip);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/jrIjB

Comment: This does not work for the following address "5957 HWY 45, EIGHT MILE, AL 36613" any suggestions, the code works fine on others, but the 2 sentence city its causing an Undefined offset error

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with sth. like:

```
(?P<address>[^,]+),\h+
(?P<city>[^,]+),\h+
(?P<state>\w+)\s+
(?P<zip>\w+)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oN5jU3/1).
In `PHP` this would be:

```
$regex = '~
           (?P<address>[^,]+),\h+ # everything that is not a comma, followed by a comma and horizontal whitespace
           (?P<city>[^,]+),\h+    # the same as above 
           (?P<state>\w+)\h+      # word characters, followed by whitespace
           (?P<zip>\w+)
          ~x';                    # verbose mode
$string = '555 Test Drive, Testville, CA 98773';
preg_match($regex, $string, $match);
echo $match["address"]; 
# 555 Test Drive
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0FIKft).
However, this can get very messy if the commas are not always there (please provide some more input strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `explode()`:

```
$full_address = '555 Test Drive, Testville, CA 98773';

$address = explode(',', $full_address)[0];
$city = explode(',', $full_address)[1];
$state = explode(' ', trim(explode(',', $full_address)[2]))[0];
$zip = explode(' ', trim(explode(',', $full_address)[2]))[1];

echo $address.'<br>';
echo $city.'<br>';
echo $state.'<br>';
echo $zip;
```